# How to convert Pandas time series into a dict with string key

Tags: python, dictionary, time, pandas, series

I need to convert a Pandas time series object into dicts which have the datetime as the key. I tried dict(my_ts_obj), but the keys are Timestamp, not string.

Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `s.index.format()` to convert the Timestamps into strings:

```
In [87]: rng = pd.date_range('12/1/2012', periods=4, freq='D')

In [88]: s = pd.Series(pd.np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

In [89]: s
Out[89]: 
2012-12-01   -1.673655
2012-12-02    1.447061
2012-12-03   -0.672347
2012-12-04    0.202692
Freq: D, dtype: float64

In [90]: dict(zip(s.index.format(), s))
Out[90]: 
{'2012-12-01': -1.6736553219187384,
 '2012-12-02': 1.4470613776383001,
 '2012-12-03': -0.67234662513200982,
 '2012-12-04': 0.20269246374288372}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is neat! I had another solution to my original problem, which is:dict((str(k), v) for k, v in s.iteritems())